# saving programmatically without changing the author

Tags: 7, cron, nodes

I made a script to change some node fields that is run by cron.

When it saves the nodes, the author changes and becomes "Anonymous".

Is there a way to save programmatically a node without changing its author?

---

Since you are asking the code, I suppose that my question is not clear.
It's not important what I change in the node. What I need is to leave the author as it is and not changing that to Anonymous.

---

Finally thanks to one comment I get that node_save() doesn't change the author. It should be something else. Thank you.

Comment: Post the code you're using.

Comment: It's very important to see your code. Using `node_save()` doesn't change the author so there must be something wrong with your code. Or if there isn't, there's something wrong elsewhere (which we're not going to be able to help without a lot more information about your site). But we do need to see your code. Please edit it into the question and flag for re-opening

Comment: thank you Clive, this is finally an answer. I did not know that node_save doesn't change the author...

Comment: Check that you are not calling node_submit($node) inside your script. This function could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Saving the node using `node_save()` does not change the author.  Example:

```
$node = node_load($nid);

$node->field_xyz['und'][0]['value'] = 'your changes';
//make the changes to field
 node_save($node);
```

Comment: this is not an answer to my question...